# Cropping with Core Image and AV Foundation

Tags: ios, camera, uiimage, avfoundation, core-image

I am taking a photo using AV Foundation, and then I went to crop that image into a square that fits my UI. In the UI, there are two semi-transparent views that show what's being captured, and I want to crop the image to include just what's in between the bottom of the top view and the top of the bottom view:

topView
|
area I want to capture and crop
|
bottom View

The actual capturing of the full image works fine. The problem is using Core Image to crop the image successfully.

```
// Custom function that takes a photo asynchronously from the capture session and gives 
// the photo and error back in a block. Works fine.
[self.captureSession takePhotoWithCompletionBlock:^(UIImage *photo, NSError *error) {
    if (photo) {
        CIImage *imageToCrop = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:photo.CGImage];

        // Find, proportionately, the y-value at which I should start the 
        // cropping, based on my UI
        CGFloat beginningYOfCrop = topView.frame.size.height * photo.size.height / self.view.frame.size.height;
        CGFloat endYOfCrop = CGRectGetMinY(bottomView.frame) * photo.size.height / self.view.frame.size.height;

        CGRect croppedFrame = CGRectMake(0,
                                         beginningYOfCrop,
                                         photo.size.width,
                                         endYOfCrop - beginningYOfCrop);

        // Attempt to transform the croppedFrame to fit Core Image's
        // different coordinate system
        CGAffineTransform coordinateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, -1.0);
        coordinateTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(coordinateTransform, 
                                                         0,
                                                         -photo.size.height);

        CGRectApplyAffineTransform(croppedFrame, coordinateTransform);

        imageToCrop = [imageToCrop imageByCroppingToRect:croppedFrame];

        // Orient the image correctly
        UIImage *filteredImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:imageToCrop
                                                     scale:1.0
                                               orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
    }
}];
```